# lastfm artist info on android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

hey guys I want to display artist info on android so i tried to parse xml 
but there is odd tag like this " CDATA "before summary of artist 
so when i run my code i got blank text view 
I trie for Json but its out of my capacity to write json parsing

here is my code

```
 String URL = "http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=artist.getinfo&artist=Cher&api_key=b25b959554ed76058ac220b7b2e0a026&limit=" + 1 + "&page=" + 1;
        XmlParser parser = new XmlParser();
        String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL); // getting XML
        Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element
                            NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName("artist");
             for (i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) 
             {
                    Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
                     name = parser.getValue(e, KEY_NAME);// name child value
                        image = parser.getValue(e, KEY_IMAGE);
                        summary = parser.getValue(e, KEY_Summary);
                                            return summary;
        } 
            return null;
    }
            @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
                    URL thumb_u;
            try {
                thumb_u = new URL(result);
                  Drawable thumb_d = Drawable.createFromStream(thumb_u.openStream(), "src");
                  tv.setText(result);//textview text set
                    icon.setImageDrawable(thumb_d);
```

Answer (score 0):

Where does `XmlParser` come from? I googled and I'm guessing it came from [here](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-xml-parsing-tutorial/)? If so, change

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
```

to add this line in `getDomElement`:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
dbf.setCoalescing(true);
```

Docs: [setCoalescing](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilderFactory.html#setCoalescing%28boolean%29)

Comment: Sir you are right I follow that tutorial ..i have added the line as you suggest to add me but still i dont get any text on my textview...still its just blank ..is this code is fine  NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName("artist");..for reference you can take a look at lastfm site into api page you will find artistinfo link so you will get better xml view

Comment: What isn't working? Note that you should only see one artist summary. Your code will also iterate through the `artist` tags in the `similar` tag, which don't contain summary tags

Comment: so how could i write code to get summary from lasfm getinfo artist?

Comment: You would need to call the API for each artist in that list. The [API](http://www.last.fm/api/show/artist.getInfo) doesn't show any way to return summaries for every similar artist

Comment: But to get artistinfo you just need apk key .. i have API key just you need to add artist name and API into your url and pass it to parser . i think you dont need to use api ? if i am right